# String as an Object Reference in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an object called "game" in my class, and I can access another object called "computer1" inside of it.

For example:

```
game.computer1.doSomeMethod()
```

However, there are three computers (computer1, computer2, computer3) and I am randomly choosing a computer, then use the String as an object reference.

My attempt:

```
var computerNumber = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
var computer:String = "computer" + String(computerNumber)
game.computer.doSomeMethod() // this line doesn't work
```

I would like to avoid passing in the random number into the object Game and a nest of if-else statements and then finally choosing to do a series of actions with the object I chose.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Use an array instead of three separate properties

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an array instead of properties?

```
class Computer {
    let number: Int

    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }

    func doSomeMethod() {
        print("doing something with computer \(number)")
    }
}

class Game
{
    var computers: [Computer]

    init() {
        computers = [Computer]()
        for i in 1...3 {
            computers.append(Computer(number: i))
        }
    }

    func callRandomComputer() {
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
        computers[random].doSomeMethod()
    }
}

let game = Game()
game.callRandomComputer()
game.callRandomComputer()
game.callRandomComputer()
```

Comment: Thank for your help!